# Driving from Haines Alaska to Anchorage Does having a felony (Domestic Violence) 15 years ago prevent me from entering and exiting Canada?

Tags: canada, us-citizens

I had a felony for domestic violence, didn't have money to fight it then. I have traveled through Europe and Mexico and Central America since and never had any problem.

Would Canada be a problem?

Comment: Maybe. It depends on the specific crime and when you finished serving your sentence and any parole.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is always the possibility. But taking into account the fact this felony was from 15 years ago, I think you should be fine. If your record has been clean ever since and that felony is your one and only on your criminal record I would say you will be fine.

However, if your criminal record has multiple felonies and offences and anyone of them were recent, you could definitely have a problem on your hands. It is worth speaking with an immigration lawyer, but probably not required. Calling the consulate might be able to help you as well (they generally suck at giving advice over the phone though).

Comment: This was the only time in my life I have been in trouble, it was a bad choice of a girlfriend who knew how to use the legal system, I was actually trying to break up with her and that was her way of fablicating a story to get me in trouble. I spent 30 days in jail in 1999, with no probation, and only a speeding ticket since.

Comment: @troywouters You only spent 30 days in jail? Are you sure you were convicted of a _felony_? Did you plead down to a misdemeanor, perhaps?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like now knowing the details a little more that you will be fine. Really the US only consider offences relating to drugs, terrorism and use of weapons or great force to be serious offences. As Michael Hampton mentioned, you might not have even been charged with a felony, it could have just been a misdemeanor. I would journey on down to the police station with your identification and ask them to take a look at their system for you.